# GCP vertex - a direct way to get deployed model ID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there a way to directly acquire the model ID from the `gcloud ai models upload` command?

Either using JSON output or value output, need to manipulate by splitting and extracting. If there is a way to directly get the model ID without manipulation, please advise.

```
output = !gcloud ai models upload \
  --region=$REGION \
  --display-name=$JOB_NAME \
  --container-image-uri=us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/prediction/tf2-cpu.2-8:latest \
  --artifact-uri=$GCS_URL_FOR_SAVED_MODEL \
  --format="value(model)"

output
-----
['Using endpoint [https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/]',
 'projects/xxxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/models/1961937762277916672',
 'Waiting for operation [8951184153827606528]...',
 '...................................done.']
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have values for `$REGION` and `$JOB_NAME`, you can use execute `gcloud ai models list` after you uploaded the model to get the model id with minimal manipulation.

See command below:

```
export REGION=us-central1
export JOB_NAME=test_training
export PROJECT_ID=your-project-name

gcloud ai models list --region=$REGION --filter="DISPLAY_NAME: $JOB_NAME" | grep "MODEL_ID" | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/\s//'
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you want to form the actual string returned by `gcloud ai models upload` you can just concatenate your variables.

```
MODEL_ID=$(gcloud ai models list --region=$REGION --filter="DISPLAY_NAME: $JOB_NAME" | grep "MODEL_ID" | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/\s//')

echo projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${REGION}/models/${MODEL_ID}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The output of `gcloud ai models describe $MODEL_NAME` includes the deployedModelId.

So if you have the MODEL_NAME, to extract just a deployedModelId:

```bash
MODEL_ID=$(gcloud ai models describe $MODEL_NAME --project=$PROJECT --region=$REGION  --flatten="deployedModels[0]" --format="csv[no-heading](deployedModelId)")
```

It will need refinement if you have many deployed versions and need to select one.